# Determine tool frame (aka measuring tool center point)

Tags: ros, calibration, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been (unsuccessfully) looking for a package that could work out the tool center point point of a tool attached to the flange of an industrial robot. Some controllers (e.g. ABB's IRC5) contain an implementation of a [4-point method to determine the TCP](http://developercenter.robotstudio.com/BlobProxy/manuals/IRC5FlexPendantOpManual/doc99.html) and it would be very useful if a similar process would be available in ROS directly.

Does anything already exists in this direction? And if not, does the 4-point method cited above have a more official name or theoretical background I could look up?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316628/determine-tool-frame-(aka-measuring-tool-center-point)/) by [gonzalocasas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34021/gonzalocasas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2019-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See whether [Jmeyer1292/tool_point_calibration](https://github.com/Jmeyer1292/tool_point_calibration) works for you.

A more generic suite of calibration tools can be found in [Jmeyer1292/robot_cal_tools](https://github.com/Jmeyer1292/robot_cal_tools).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gonzalocasas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34021/gonzalocasas/) on 2019-02-26**:
Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-26**:
Let us know what your experiences are with that package.